# Sinatra application cannot find views directory

Tags: ruby, view, sinatra

I am trying to create a modular sinatra application and need each of my sub-applications to look for the `views` directory at the root of my project's folder. But it only looks up the views directory in the sub-directory itself instead of the root. Here's what my project looks like:

```
├── config.ru
├── music_catalog
│   └── app.rb
├── public
│   ├── css
│   │   └── site.css
│   └── images
│       ├── content_top_bg.jpg
│       ├── demo_image_01.jpg
│       ├── god_save_http_it_aint_no_human_being.png
│       ├── header_bg.jpg
│       ├── home-showcase.png
│       ├── hover_link_bg.jpg
│       ├── its_little_its_blue_and_its_magical.jpeg
│       ├── linkbar_bg.jpg
│       ├── logo.png
│       ├── main_graphics.jpg
│       ├── placeholder.gif
│       ├── placeholder.jpg
│       ├── placeholder.png
│       ├── right_navbar_bg.jpg
│       └── shadow_left.jpg
└── views
    ├── album.haml
    ├── genre.haml
    ├── index.haml
    ├── layout.haml
    ├── login.haml
    └── not_found.haml
```

So in my config.ru I try doing this:

```
require 'sinatra'

require './music_catalog/app.rb'

set :root, File.dirname(__FILE__)


# enable :run

map "/" do
   run MusicCatalog
end
```

In `app.rb` inside of `music_catalog` I use the root variable like so:

```
require 'sinatra/base'

`# I thing I am doing this wrong`

set :views, Proc.new { File.join(root, "sites/#{site}/views") }

class MusicCatalog < Sinatra::Base
   get "/" do
      haml :index
   end
end
```

But instead of pulling out my `index.haml` out of my root directory, it errors out like so:

```
Errno::ENOENT at /
No such file or directory - /Users/amiterandole/Dropbox/code/rsandbox/sinatra_music_store/music_catalog/views/index.haml
```

I am using `ruby 1.9.3p194`

Please help me set the views directory to the proper location in the root `views` folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. The set :views statement should actually be inside my app class like this:

```
class MusicCatalog < Sinatra::Base

  **set :views, Proc.new { File.join(root, "../views") }**

  get "/" do
    haml :index
  end
end
```

Also I was joining the root in the wrong way earlier. Fixed that. Now sinatra is correctly loading my templates

Comment: Well done. I was just gonna link you my git hub project.. con gratz though